# Can this Neo4j query be optimized?

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have rather large dataset (20mln nodes, 200mln edges), simplest **shortestPath** queries finish in milliseconds, everything is great.

But... I need to allow **shortestPath** to have ZERO or ONE relation of type 999 and it can be only the first from the start node.

So, my query became like this:

```
MATCH (one:Obj{oid:'startID'})-[r1*0..1]-(b:Obj) 
WHERE all(rel in r1 where rel.val = 999) 
WITH one, b 
MATCH (two:Obj{oid:'endID'}), path=shortestPath((one) -[0..21]-(two)) 
WHERE ALL (x IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) 
WHERE (x.val > -1 and x.val<101) or (x.val=999 or x.val=998)) return path
```

it runs in milliseconds when there's a short path (up to 2-4), but can take 5 or 20 seconds for paths like 5++. Maybe I've composed inefficient query?

This question will be bountied when available.

Comment: When removing last condition "WHERE ALL (x IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) 
WHERE (x.val > -1 and x.val<101) or (x.val=999 or x.val=998))" performance improves greatly, but I need this condition :(

Comment: We don't know what indexes you have, and your query looks like it has been reformulated away from your domain, making this a lot harder to answer.  Can you post the result of `EXPLAIN` on your actual query so we can see the plan being executed?

Comment: Also, why is `b` in this query, it's not in the second match or in `RETURN`, it looks like wasted work.  Also, if you have relationship types you should be using them on those paths...they don't discriminate based on relType, and you're looking for very long paths through ANY relationship UNDIRECTED.  If you'd specify the order of the rel and a suitable type (or set of types) it'd probably get a lot better already, but this depends on aspects of your data we can't see.

Comment: Thank you for helping! At first I've searched for shortestpath between b and two, but it showed all appendixes of path one-b (in visual mode). Changing to shortestpath between one and two displayed the same routes without unnecessary appendixes. But slow... As been suggested relationships[0] is the right way to put condition on first relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your requirements are a bit unclear to me, so I'll reiterate my understanding and offer a solution.

You want to inspect the shortest paths between a start and end node.

The paths returned should have ZERO or ONE relationship with a val of 999.  If it's ONE relationship with that value, it should be the first.

Here's an attempt based on that logic:

```
 MATCH (start:Obj {oid:'startID'}),
       (end:Obj {oid:'endID'}),
       path=shortestPath((start)-[1..21]->(end))
  WITH path, relationships(path) AS rels
 WHERE all(r IN relationships WHERE r.val != 999)
    OR (relationships[0].val = 999
        AND all(r IN relationships[1..] WHERE r.val != 999))
RETURN path
```

I haven't had a chance to test on actual data, but hopefully this logic and approach at least point you in the right direction.

Also note: it's possible the entire WHERE clause at the end could be reduced to:

```
 WHERE all(r IN relationships[1..] WHERE r.val != 999)
```

Meaning you don't even need to check the first relationship.

Comment: Huge thanks, Jonathan! The operator relationships[0] was what I missed! Will start bounty tomorrow, you are winner. Longer option has several syntax errors, but shorter one worked great. Just... <> instead of != and relationships(path)[1..] instead of relationships[1..]

Comment: oh cool, glad it helped.  I guess I meant to say rels[1..].  Good catch on the not-equals, that one catches me quite often in my adhoc querying... old habits die hard. :)

Comment: You could also do `WHERE ALL(r in TAIL(RELATIONSHIPS(path)) WHERE r.val != 999)`. That way you don't need the with, and the query can terminate earlier. (rest of [functions](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/))

Comment: Oh, man! Your query bit me sooooo hard today. It just silently ignores some paths even of length 2. shortestpath between a-b-c is not found, between a-b is, between b-c also. Will try to report a bug to Neo... :(((